# .bat check if the page has flash yes or not

Tags: javascript, batch-file, flash

The idea is to create a **.bat or .html** file that when i run it tells me whether a url has a Flash object or not.
If webpage have **Flash Object**, show me a echo and if don't have show me another echo.

I have this .bat ... This thing, seems to check if the page is on or off. But I don't get to check if webpage has a Flash object or not :( This can be done?

```html
@echo off
  setlocal
  set "URL1=https://www.google.com/"
  cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" %URL1%
  if %ErrorLevel% EQU 200 (
    echo %URL1% Online
  ) else (
    echo %URL1% Off
  )
 pause
  goto :EOF
  
  JScript */
  with(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")){
  open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0));send();
  while(readyState!=4){WSH.Sleep(50)};
  WSH.Quit(status)}
```

I appreciate any help no matter how long it happens. If you know a free program that does this also helps me.

Thank for read and get nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) (it should be in the same directory):

```
::testing site with flash
call winhttpjs.bat http://flash.org/video.php -saveto res.html
find /i  "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" "res.html" >nul 2>nul && (
  echo site has flash
)||(
  echo site has NO flash
)

::testing site WITHOUT flash
call winhttpjs.bat https://www.google.bg -saveto res.html
find /i  "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" "res.html" >nul 2>nul && (
  echo site has flash
)||(
  echo site has NO flash
)
```