# findstr on remote site/server

Tags: batch-file, findstr

You can't `findstr` to a site like this:

```
findstr /v "Something" www.example.com/example.txt
```

or something like that.
is there a way to get that working or something simallar?

Comment: i will not be there when i get the answer #BlameSchool

Comment: first you'll have to download the page/text and then check. You can use the same technique as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022632/bat-check-if-the-page-has-flash-yes-or-not/48022851#48022851)

Comment: thanks but i'm a noob so i can't realy translate that to what i want

Comment: `findstr` is built to work with a (local) file. So you have to download the file to your computer first. Btw: `www.example.com/example.txt` is a valid path\filename, so the literal answer would be: `Create that file`

Comment: You can look a BitsAdmin. `bitsadmin /transfer myJob /download /priority normal "http://www.microsoft.com" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Myfile.html"`

Answer (score 0):

Batch file is not a good language for your task.

Use PowerShell. With it, you can do this in one line and without any external dependency.

```powershell
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.example.com/example.txt").Content -Split "[`r`n]" |
    Select-String -Pattern "Something" -NotMatch
```